# What is "AiMT" on HP’s latest BIOS’?

Tags: bios

Oh HP's latest BIOS (for laptop, but I think they are similar to desktops) under advanced (which have well, every single BIOS option) there is an option that doesn't have any help text and which the manual completely ignores.

It is called AiMT and is disabled by default.
It is right under APMF (AMD platform management framework) which is enabled by default.
And under “AiMT” there is `Sanitization Model Countdown Timer` which is a dropdown with numeric values (no time unit anywhere. sigh).

Defaults to "120". Range from 15 to 300.

```
[X] APMF
[ ] AiMT
Sanitization Mode Countdown Timer: [ 120    ][V]
```

What is AiMT?

Comment: It's probably the same as iAMT [Intel Active Management Technology - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology)

Comment: It most certainly stands for [AMD Integrated Management Technology (AIM-T)](https://developer.amd.com/tools-for-dmtf-dash/)

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks. that is what i'm inclined to believe too. But why would they invent a new name?! also this system have no Intel chipsets. all hp custom, non-intel options for wifi, disk controller, etc, and AMD apu.

Comment: @gcb - They wouldn't create a new name, they would simply use the AMD equivalent version of the feature, which for Intel based hardware is `Intel Active Management Technology (Intel AMT)`and AMD based hardware would be `AMD Integrated Technology (AMD IMT)`.

Answer (score 1):

> “It most certainly stands for AMD Integrated Management Technology ([AIM-T](https://developer.amd.com/tools-for-dmtf-dash/))” — [Ramhound’s comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1764527/what-is-aimt-on-hp-latest-bioses#comment2744978_1764527).

---

> “It’s probably the same as [iAMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology) Intel Active Management Technology.” — [DavidPostill’s comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1764527/what-is-aimt-on-hp-s-latest-bios/1764586?noredirect=1#comment2744976_1764527).

Not verified in any way, but those comments are likely the correct answer.

Comment: @Ramhound I am the one who fleshed out the comment quotes; I assume it is fine now? If not, please feel free to edit.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - Original quote was wrong too, but yes, it’s fine.